# How to typeset article to look like 1945 Biometrika article

Tags: fonts, formatting, typography, article

I recently read this classic article by Leslie in Biometrika in 1945:

https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/33/3/183/215959?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Old mathematical papers often look much worse than their modern successors, including in Biometrika, but this article struck me as genuinely beautiful. How can I make my articles have the same appearance using TeX? As a start, I have tried to work out what font it is, but so far without any success.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/?

Comment: using amsart and a package giving a times like font eg newtxtext/newtxmath would get you some of the way there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this is very helpful thank you. I think I ought to be able to achieve the format of the matrices and tables. I confess I remain confused as to why their typesetting got worse (imho)!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is there a way to make the font thicker/heavier as it is in the Biometrika paper compared to what I get with newtxtext and newtxmath

Comment: there are thousands of fonts, you just need to find one closer you can't really change the font itself to be different (or at least not easily)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Fixed - although now gated unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `amsart` class and a package giving a times like font eg `newtxtext` / `newtxmath` would get you some of the way there.